# using logback in a client server program

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, slf4j, logback

I need to use **logback** in a client server program, for each request that comes to server, it creates a new service which will run in a separate thread. I need to log actions that happen during service excecution. But i dont want to generate separate logger object for each service thread. I know that one solution would be to set the logger object as static. So it wont be instanciated every time but is there any standard solution for this kind of problem. bellow are some code snippets from my source code:

The *server* class which creates a separate servcie thread for each request:

[image]

1: a logger specific for server class.

2: for each incomming request that comes to server we generate a new thread (new instance of service class),but the question is that we dont want  to have a logger instances for each service instance (i guess it is a bad practice!)

and here is the *service* class :

[image]

*:logger is defined static so it wont be instanciated for each service class instance:

Comment: It will be a lot easier for us to help you if you post the code in [markdown format](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) instead of screenshots so we could copy/paste with edits into our answers, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i know that one solution would be to set the logger object as static so it wont be instanciated every time but is there any standard solution for this kind of problem.

This is what I do in my application. It works great.

Many of my classes have this as the first line:

```
public class SomeClass {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeClass.class);

    // the rest of the class
}
```

---

[Also, if you want the log messages to reflect which overall request is the one doing the logging, you should use MDC:](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html)

> One of the design goals of logback is to audit and debug complex distributed applications. Most real-world distributed systems need to deal with multiple clients simultaneously. In a typical multithreaded implementation of such a system, different threads will handle different clients. A possible but slightly discouraged approach to differentiate the logging output of one client from another consists of instantiating a new and separate logger for each client. This technique promotes the proliferation of loggers and may increase their management overhead.

Read the entire link, it does a better job of explaining MDC than I ever could.

Comment: i use this solution too (i mean defining the logger static) i also used MDC (it is show in the question)but my problem is that why you have used final keyword.

Comment: @user3593084 Because it's always the same `Logger`, instantiated when the class is created.

Comment: @user3593084 Sure, but I [always use `final` in fields that I know don't change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827495/always-use-final)

Comment: sorry to ask again but static would make this attribute unique across all the class instances and also we are initializing the class instance with the same parameter (in this case SomeClass.class) so we dont need the final keyword